# Composer Require florianv/swap requirements not met

Tags: php, composer-php

When I run the command `composer require florianv/swap php-http/message php-http/guzzle6-adapter`

I get the following error...

*I am using PHP 7.2 on a Homestead vagrant box*

> Using version ^3.4 for florianv/swap
>   Using version ^1.7 for php-http/message
>   Using version ^2.0 for php-http/guzzle6-adapter
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install php-http/guzzle6-adapter v2.0.0
>       - don't install php-http/guzzle6-adapter 2.x-dev|install php-http/guzzle6-adapter dev-master
>       - Installation request for php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[2.x-dev, v2.0.0].
>       - Installation request for florianv/swap ^3.4 -> satisfiable by florianv/swap[3.4.0].
>       - Conclusion: don't install php-http/httplug v1.1.0
>       - florianv/swap 3.4.0 requires florianv/exchanger ^1.1 -> satisfiable by florianv/exchanger[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.x-dev].
>       - florianv/exchanger 1.1.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.0.0-RC1, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.0-alpha2, v1.0.0-alpha3, v1.0.0-beta, v1.1.0].
>       - florianv/exchanger 1.1.1 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.0.0-RC1, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.0-alpha2, v1.0.0-alpha3, v1.0.0-beta, v1.1.0].
>       - florianv/exchanger 1.1.2 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.0.0-RC1, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.0-alpha2, v1.0.0-alpha3, v1.0.0-beta, v1.1.0].
>       - florianv/exchanger 1.2.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.0.0-RC1, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.0-alpha2, v1.0.0-alpha3, v1.0.0-beta, v1.1.0].
>       - florianv/exchanger 1.2.1 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.0.0-RC1, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.0-alpha2, v1.0.0-alpha3, v1.0.0-beta, v1.1.0].
>       - florianv/exchanger 1.2.2 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.0.0-RC1, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.0-alpha2, v1.0.0-alpha3, v1.0.0-beta, v1.1.0].
>       - florianv/exchanger 1.x-dev requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.0.0-RC1, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.0-alpha2, v1.0.0-alpha3, v1.0.0-beta, v1.1.0].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, 2.0.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v1.0.0-RC1, 2.0.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v1.0.0-alpha, 2.0.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v1.0.0-alpha2, 2.0.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v1.0.0-alpha3, 2.0.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v1.0.0-beta, 2.0.x-dev].
>       - php-http/guzzle6-adapter dev-master requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0].
>       - Conclusion: don't install php-http/httplug v2.0.0|install php-http/httplug v1.1.0
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.